# SaveChanges() isn't passing some values to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, savechanges, editorfor

This is my `cshtml`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

   <fieldset>
    <legend>Item do Pedido</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Pedido_Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Fornecedor_Id)   

    ...

     <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pedido, "Pedido")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pedido)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pedido)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Recolha, "Recolha")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Recolha)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Recolha)
    </div> 

    ...
```

The values of `Pedido` and `Recolha` arrive in the controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(ItemPedido1 itempedido)
        {
            try
            {
                ViewBag.Fornecedor_Id = itempedido.Fornecedor_Id;
                var listItens = db.ItensFornecedor1.Where(f => f.Fornecedor_Id == itempedido.Fornecedor_Id);
                List<Produtos1> listProdutos = new List<Produtos1>();
                foreach (var item in listItens)
                {
                    listProdutos.Add(db.Produtos1.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == item.Item_Id));
                }
                ViewBag.Item_Id = new SelectList(listProdutos, "Id", "Descricao");
            ViewBag.UnidadeMedida_Id = new SelectList(db.UnidadesMedida1, "Id", "Descricao");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
```

All okay here itempedido has all the form values:

[image]

```
db.ItemPedido1.Add(itempedido);
```

Now lets save the changes:

```
db.SaveChanges();
```

**Poof!!** and the `Pedido`/`Recolha` values disappear...
[image]

```
                return RedirectToAction("SelecionarFornecedor", new { id = itempedido.Pedido_Id });
            }
            return View(itempedido);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //return Content("Campos com * devem ser preenchidos");
            TempData["ErrorMsg"] = "-msg_111";
            return View(itempedido); //funcionou
        }
    }
```

Consider that:

- I inserted the Pedido and Recolha recently in my db
- I am new to C# :(
- And this is Pedidos1:

  ```
     namespace Wavebar.Data
     {
      using System;
      using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Pedidos1
     {
      public Pedidos1()
      {
      this.CotacoesFornecedor1 = new HashSet<CotacoesFornecedor1>();
      this.ItemPedido1 = new HashSet<ItemPedido1>();
    }

  public int Id { get; set; }
  public decimal ValorTotal { get; set; }
  public int Evento_Id { get; set; }
  public int Status { get; set; }
  public string Endereco { get; set; }
  public System.DateTime Data { get; set; }
  public int Bar_Id { get; set; }
  public string Observacao { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<CotacoesFornecedor1> CotacoesFornecedor1 { get; set; }
  public virtual EVENTOS EVENTOS { get; set; }
  public virtual EVENTOS_BARES EVENTOS_BARES { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<ItemPedido1> ItemPedido1 { get; set; }
  }
  ```

Comment: It will be a good idea if you show the Entity Model classes.

Comment: Are there any Foreign Key constraints you're missing?

You can view the EF debug information in the output window by adding:
db.Database.Log = d => Debug.WriteLine(d); within the scope of your dbContext

Comment: The `ItemPedido1` entity has a `Produtos1` relationship. When the new `ItemPedido1` is added, it has a `Produtos1` entity attached. If this `Produtos1` does not exist in database it will be inserted too. Probably `Produtos1` has a `Recolha` property that does not accept NULL values in database. Can you show Pedidos1 Model Class?

Comment: @Balde I have updated the post.

Comment: @Balde i updated the `Recolha` to allow nulls, now every submited form came with `null` value in `Recolha`